# Why isn't the URL being executed?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, url, razor

I have this little bit of JS code:

```
$("#ProcessGroupRevisions").change(function () {
    if (this.value  == -1) {
        var processId = $("#Processes").prop("value");
        '@Url.Action("AddNewRevision","SetpointManagement") ? processGroupId =' + @ViewBag.ProcessGroupId + '& processId=' + processId;
     }
});
```

When this files, the generated URL is as follows:

[image]

The problem is that the URL is never executed. The view is never loaded. What do I need to change to actually execute the URL?

Comment: What language is this `'@Url.Action...` thing ? You probably should add a tag.

Comment: @dystroy I believe it is C# in Visual Studio. Just added the tag.

Comment: `Url.Action()` only returns a URL - you can use that to make an AJAX call, but your code here isn't doing anything more with it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have spaces before and after a question `?` mark. And then after `=`. And then a space after `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. The solution is as follows:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("AddNewRevision","SetpointManagement")?processGroupId=' + @ViewBag.ProcessGroupId + '&processId=' + processId;
```

Comment: Redirection hasn't crossed my mind when you said "URL is never executed". :) It could have a GET request for some data modification, etc.